# When button clicked +1

Tags: c#, button

This is about the easiest thing ever. I'm doing some exercises and already did this one but deleted it. I remember this took me 2 min, and now i don't know how to do it.

All I want is when the button is clicked a Label will go + 1

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
int Amount;
Amount = 0;
Amount++;
Label.Content = Amount;
}
```

I know this is wrong because every time you press Amount will become 0  again.

Comment: Then read back the value of Amount from your label

Comment: You need to declare Amount at the class level to keep track between clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the scope of the variable amount. Declare amount at a class level and it should work.

```
private int Amount = 0;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Amount++;
    Label.Content = Amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the amount as a field, or some other way of having the value exist beyond the life of the button click handler:

```
private int Amount = 0;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Amount++;
    Label.Content = Amount;
}
```

Here, the `Amount` because a field associated with the instance of your Window.

Comment: Wouldn't he need to convert `Amount` to a string before assigning it to the label?

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp No, [`Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF is an `object`, not a string. WPF takes care of deciding how to display the object.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you hit the button, first you set Amount to zero, then you increment it. You have to remove this variable from the button and set it on another place.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Amount outside of all methods. You're just resetting it every time you click to 0.